# What is a good Mac objective-c 2D game engine?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, game-engine

Now that Apple is going to release the Mac App Store there is bound to be lots of games. I'm curious, in your opinion, what is a good Mac 2D game engine to use for game development that has an objective-c interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cocos2D which I understand is popular for the iPhone also now [has Mac support](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1074).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Comment: @PruitIgoe: I was talking about the iPHone version which has now been ported to Mac. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/  The distinction is important because you use python for the standard framework and Objective-C for the iPhone framework.

Comment: Kobold2D (http://www.kobold2d.com) makes Mac OS development with Cocos2D even easier and has better support for cross-platform (iOS & Mac) development.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the most widely popular is [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/), although I would suggest to go with either [Kobold2D](http://www.kobold2d.com) (free) or [KoboldTouch](http://www.koboldtouch.com) (subscription, in active development).

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information about Cocos2D here:

http://macoun.de/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/6GS10.zip

Those are the materials from this year's Macoun' session on Cocos2D. It has some slides (german only, sorry) as well as some links and the sources. The slides have some examples. Might help to get you startet.

Cheers,
Marcus

Answer (score 0):

"Love" is an epic game engine http://love2d.org/

Although it's not objective-c (it's lua)

At the time of writing i haven't tried it yet.